# how does SetupAssistant treat uid numbers when moving users from an old machine to a newly installed OS?

Tags: time-machine, user-account, migration, setup-assistant

I have two users on my 2019 iMac. (Ventura 13.5.2) I want to use SetupAssistant to move these users accounts to my brand new Macmini.
The instructions for Setup Assistant indicate that on your first boot you will create a user account on the new machine before Setup Assistant moves data from the old machine.  Does it matter what I name that first user? Does it have to be exactly the same name as at least one of the users on the old machine? Will this first user automatically get uid 501?

The user 'Tom' on the old mac has uid 501 on the old Mac so has Admin privileges, the user 'Thomas' has uid 502 and wasn't granted Admin privileges. When I run Setup Assistant and migrate Tom and Thomas to the new machine, will I end up with three accounts if the first user I created on the new machine isn't named Tom or Thomas?

If I want to end up with only two accounts do I need to name the first user I create on the new machine Tom or Thomas? If I name the first user on the new machine Thomas before I tell Setup Assistant to migrate all the users on the old machine, will the uid of Tom on the new machine end up as 502?

Comment: I haven't done this in a while [I think maybe Catalina when I did it, using the then Migration Assistant, Ive never used Setup Assistant] - but you need to run your migrate as part of your initial setup, & not make a new account. The new admin account will be 501, as it's the first on there. Your others would then get 502 & 503. This is, as you can imagine, a complete PITA. Last time I fell for that I unpicked it all by hand - I won't be doing that ever again.

Comment: Setup Assistant seems to be part of an MDM solution - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depdeff4a547/web - is that what you're using? If so, I'd refer to the particular MDM's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migration of users and UID happen before the setup assistant offers to make a new admin account, so your old UID are preserved when you adopt a backup after installing a new OS.

If you happened to run the setup assistant before you realized this you’ll need to erase the Mac (backing up) and then choose the other backup to restore. Then you’d have to hand restore things into the correct user folders if you intend to use the backup of the “mistake” setup.

Comment: Having done the 'by hand' rejig once, I'd heartily recommend a nuke & pave - it will be quicker & easier.

Comment: Yes, the hope is the OP hasn’t already run setup and have data to migrate. @Tetsujin. I needed to edit my post to make that more clear.